# inverse reshaping giving different results

Tags: python, numpy

I need to resize and then reshape certain image. Then I want to apply the inverse reshaping which should give the original picture, but it is not working. Let us have this code:

```
images=[]
image = imread('1.png')
resized = np.resize(image, (320, 440))
images.append(resized)

arr=np.asarray(images)
newArray=arr.astype('float32')

plt.figure(figsize=[5, 5])
reshaped = np.reshape(newArray[0], (320,440))
plt.imshow(reshaped, cmap='gray')
plt.show()
```

Original picture `1.png`:

[image]

Reshaped picture shown by plt.show():
[image]

Inverse reshaped image is not like the original, can someone tell me where is the problem? Thanks.

Comment: Resizing and reshaping are two fundamentally different operations!

Comment: I suspect that `newArray[0]` is the culprate, try just `newArray`

Comment: Nothing happend, I wrote it that way because In future I inted to reshape more images in cycle.

Comment: I don't think you want to use `np.resize` on an image, or image like array.  Use a image resizing tool.   `np.resize` expands or truncates an array in a 1 dimensional way, without scaling or interpolation.

Comment: I do not necessarily need the scaling or interpolation.

Comment: Why are you using `np.resize`?  What do you expect it to do?  Have you tested it on a small array that you can examine in detail? What's the `shape` of `image` before `resize`?

Comment: You got a point, my approach is wrong. I wanted to reacreate sometnig like this: `img=misc.imresize(img,(224,224))`, unfortunatly this function imresize was removed from misc, so I used np.resize which does completly different thing. The new problem is: use the right resizing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit:

After clarification, it looks like the confusion comes from `np.resize`, which is not an image processing operation, and is not used for rescaling an image while retaining content.

It looks as though image processing wrappers such as `imresize` have been removed from the `scipy` library, and while you can in principle use the `scipy.interpolate` package to reproduce the functionality of `imresize`, I recommend either using `pillow`, or `scikit-image`

with `pillow`:

```
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
image = Image.open("my_image.jpg")
image = image.resize((224, 224))
image = np.asarray(image)  # convert to numpy
```

with `sckit-image`:

```
from skimage.transform import resize
image = imread("my_image.jpg")
image = resize(image, (224, 224))
```

---

original answer

`np.reshape` will first ravel the elements, then sort them into the new shape specified, losing a lot of spatial relationships, as you're seeing.  Likely, what you actually want to do is `np.transpose` the image, swapping two axes:

```
images=[]
image = imread('1.png')
resized = np.resize(image, (320, 440))
images.append(resized)

arr=np.asarray(images)
newArray=arr.astype('float32')

plt.figure(figsize=[5, 5])
transposed = np.transpose(newArray[0])
plt.imshow(transposed, cmap='gray')
plt.show()
```

Comment: This just rotates the picture. Not what I wanted.

Comment: I'm not entirely clear on your intent.  The image already has the dimensions (320, 440) after applying `np.resize`.  You want an inverse operation to `np.resize`?  You would at least need the original image dimensions, along with the condition that the resized shape is larger than the original image, or else you'll have destroyed any information outside of those bounds.  The inverse operation is simply:  `orig_image = resized[:image.shape[0], :image.shape[1]]`

Comment: I am trying to recreate the image proccesing functions in this example: https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/fingerprint-deep-learning . The problem ist misc is deprecated so it is not working as it supposed to be. Also I have my own dataset with dimensions 320x440. I admit, there may be more errors and mistakes in my code, I am new to python.

Comment: ah, I see. `imresize` has a totally different functionality and intent from `np.resize`, the former is an image processing operation, the second is just an operation on array size/shape and isn't designed for images (where there is spatial meaning to the array data).  Since the tutorial uses `scikit-image`, just use `skimage.transform.resize` instead.

Comment: I used the pillow approach which you wrote, now I am able to resize the picture, but I can not reshape it after setting it to asaray and astype(float). This is the error: ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 150528 into shape (224,224). Do you know what is happening?

Comment: I think I know where is the problem, I can not reshape it to the (224,224) because it hase third dimension which is the color of pixel in RGB so, I will now try to continue coding, thanks.